# Single Ultrasonic Sensor for Raspberry pi 2B+ not functioning from Pi Terminal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I have been working with 4-pin HC-SRO4 ultrasonic sensors, up to four at a time. I have been developing code to make 4 of these sensors work simultaneously and after reorganizing wires for installation on a project and using the basic code to run one, I cannot make the sensor function. Code follows:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

TRIG1 = 15
ECHO1 = 13
start1 = 0
stop1 = 0

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(TRIG1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(TRIG1, 0)

GPIO.setup(ECHO1, GPIO.IN)
while True:
       time.sleep(0.1)

       GPIO.output(TRIG1, 1)
       time.sleep(0.00001)
       GPIO.output(TRIG1, 0)

       while GPIO.input(ECHO1) == 0:
               start1 = time.time()
               print("here")

       while GPIO.input(ECHO1) == 1:
               stop1 = time.time()
               print("also here")
       print("sensor 1:")
       print (stop1-start1) * 17000

GPIO.cleanup()
```

After changing wires, sensors, and other components within the circuit (including the GPIO pins) I have looked at the code, and added print statements to the terminal to see which parts of the code are running. The 1st print statement
`print("here")`
executes consistently, but the second print statement`print("also here")` does not, and I am at a loss for an explanation. In other words, why is the second while loop not being executed? Other questions asked here have not worked for my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial by Gaven MacDonald that might help with this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xACy8l3LsXI

First of all, the while block with `ECHO1 == 0` would loop forever until the ECHO1 becomes 1. In this period of time, the code inside would be executed again and again. You wouldn't want to set the time again and again, so you can do something like this:

```
while GPIO.input(ECHO1) == 0:
    pass #This is here to make the while loop do nothing and check again.

start = time.time() #Here you set the start time.

while GPIO.input(ECHO1) == 1:
    pass #Doing the same thing, looping until the condition is true.

stop = time.time()

print (stop - start) * 170 #Note that since both values are integers, python would multiply the value with 170. If our values were string, python would write the same string again and again: for 170 times.
```

Also, just as a best practice, you should use try except blocks to safely exit the code. Such as:

```
try:
    while True:
        #Code code code...
except KeyboardInterrupt: #This would check if you have pressed Ctrl+C
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I've actually already used the youtube video, but thanks for the code help, It fixed the problem. Thanks again, Haydon